# compilation error of c code to web assembly

Tags: c, clang, homebrew, llvm, webassembly

I am trying to compile a simple C code to web assembly

```bash
$ clang --target=wasm32 main.c -o primes.wasm
main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

This is very weird because I *do* have `wasm32` target:

```bash
$ llc --version | grep wasm32
    wasm32      - WebAssembly 32-bit
```

and I *can* compile to my *native* target:

```bash
$ rm main && clang main.c -o main && file main
main: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

In addition, I made sure I *do* have the `stdio.h` file:

```bash
$ find /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include -name stdio.h 
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1/stdio.h
```

And it seems I *am* using the *same* path for `clang`:

```bash
$ which clang
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang
```

I'm pretty sure the actual C code is irrelevant - but will paste it at the end if requested in the comments

Answer (score 1):

It seems I can achieve my goal with [https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-sdk](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-sdk#install):

```
$ wget https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-sdk/releases/download/wasi-sdk-20/wasi-sdk-20.0-macos.tar.gz
$ tar xvf wasi-sdk-20.0-macos.tar.gz
$ wasi-sdk-20.0/bin/clang main.c -o primes.wasm
```

No flags are needed (actually, it *doesn't* work with the above flags).

Answer (score 0):

tiny-wasm-runtime is another simple option to compile C for web assembly:

- github.com/twiddlingbits/tiny-wasm-runtime
- or npm install tiny-wasm-runtime

You can print from C to a <div> or <canvas>, or draw to a <canvas>